# Thermal deformation of plastic

Tags: modifiers

My question is a variation of one posed in July 2014 using this blender file:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95913396/extendedgauntlet1longer.blend

[image]

Instead of flattening the top as originally requested, I want to flatten the object by spreading the wings.  The very top can not be deformed at all as it has interlocking parts.  Basically the lower 3 mm or so, i.e. the thickness of the wings, is what I'd like to deform and flatten.  I've tried the suggestion for the July post and looked at several softbody tutorials and I'm not getting it.

Thanks.

Hertfordkc

Comment: Could you include some screenshots? I'm glad you included the .blend file, but I don't like to download them unless I have to :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish (a sketch of the desired result might help) and how much patience you have, you may want to use either [sculpt mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/sculpt_paint/sculpting/introduction.html#introduction) or [proportional editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html?#proportional-editing) in edit mode.

Sculpt mode is helpful if you have a large number of vertices, or if you want to deform meshes with natural strokes of the mouse. If you need more precise control, proportional editing allows you to move individual verts/edges/faces around, and the neighboring geometry will "stretch" in similar ways. Both of these allow you to adjust the radius of effect.

Comment: When I've tried proportional editing, edges get flattened.  I haven't ventured into sculpt yet, but I'll take a look.

Comment: Trying to clarify...look at the object as having something rigid mounted on top, transforming into something like stiff leather.  Said another way, this object will 3d print a lot faster if printed flat.  Then it can be thermally deformed to the shape in the file.  Everything I've read about soft body says that's the ticket, but it may take a decade of experience for me to figure it out.